# pytorch min by columns with nan

Tags: nan, tensor, torch, minimum

I have a 2D torch tensor with nan values, I would like to get column minimum values and ignore cells with nan values.

```
import torch

data = torch.tensor([[ 0.,  1., float('nan'),  3.],[ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.], [ 8.,  9., 10., 11.]])
torch.min(data,0)

# What I would like to get is
# tensor([0., 1., 6., 3.])
```

Is there all suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by converting all the nan values in the tensor to an incredible high value and then running torch.min:

```
 #I am replacing nan with 10^15
 data = torch.nan_to_num(data,nan = 10e14)
 data = torch.min(data,0)
```

torch.nan_to_num is used to turn all the nan values in your tensors to a certain value. Manipulate that as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for very useful suggestion. It works with your solution. Here I also want to add another solution that I just found `mask = ~torch.isnan(data)` and then 
`colMins = torch.FloatTensor([torch.min(torch.masked_select(data[:,i], mask[:,i])) for i in range(data.shape[1])])`

Comment: @tamnva Sure! Will try your solution as well